# Cannot find module 'fs/promises' even when I use the fs code only inside "getStaticProps()" - next js

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, server-side-rendering, development-environment

So, I use latest version of next js ^11.1.2. According to the documentation, using server side (node js) codes inside getStaticProps() function is fine as it removes the 'fs' import from the client side build.

But in my case its not working.

The following code is what I did...

```
    import fs from "fs/promises";
    import path from "path";
    
    function HomePage(props) {
      return (
        <ul>
          {props.products.map((el) => (
            <li key={el.id}>{el.title}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      );
    }
    
    export async function getStaticProps() {
      try {
        let data = await fs.readFileSync(
          path.join(process.cwd(), "data", "dummy-backend.json")
        );
        console.log(data);
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        return {
          props: {
            products: data.products,
          },
        };
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return {
          props: {
            products: [],
            error: "Error in fetching data",
          },
        };
      }
    }
    
    export default HomePage;
```

[Picture of the error displayed in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYoRn.png)

And I'm in the development environment.

Comment: Which Node.js version are you using? `fs/promises` is not available on versions less than 14.

Comment: I was using node js v12.16.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';
```

Instead of

```
import fs from "fs/promises";
```

and change `fs.readFileSync` to `fs.readFile`.